# Rails helper form_for() ignores the url parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting the error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"):`

When doing a POST from `/articles/new` page.

My erb code inside the `/app/views/articles/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

 <p>
   <%= f.submit %>
 </p>
```

`/bin/rake routes` output:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 1067
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
<%= form_for Article.new do |f| %>
```

Read about how to use [resources with `form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style) in the Ruby docs.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not help. Any other suggestions? Maybe suggestion on how to debug such a thing?

Comment: Can you please post your `config/routes.rb`? Did you restart your server after adding the article routes to that file?

Comment: This is an official proof of my dumbness I guess. I just was pressing back after I submitted the form and never actually refreshing the form with the code changes I have made. After I tried raising exceptions and it did not work this became apparent. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After I tried raising exceptions and it not working I became suspicious. then I realized that the page with the form was never refreshed in the browser. I was just pressing back and resubmitting the form. Dumb mistake.

ALWAYS DO HARD (no browser cache) REFRESHES!!!